# feature_importances_ showing up as NoneType in ExtraTreesClassifier :TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nonetype

I am trying to select important features (or at least understand which features explain more variabilty) for a given dataset. Towards this I use both ExtraTreesClassifier and GradientBoostingRegressor - and then use :-

```
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=10,max_features='auto',random_state=0) # stops after 10 estimation passes, right ?
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
feature_importance=clf.feature_importances_  # does NOT work - returns NoneType for feature_importance
```

Post this **I am really interested** in plotting them(for visual representation) - or even preliminary, just **looking at the relative order of importance and the corresponding indices**

```
# Both of these do not work as the feature_importance is of NoneType
feature_importance = 100.0 * (feature_importance / feature_importance.max())
indices = numpy.argsort(feature_importance)[::-1]
```

What I found puzzling was - if I were to use GradientBoostingRegressor as below, I do get the feature_importance and the indices thereof. What am I doing wrong ?

```
#Works with GradientBoostingRegressor
params = {'n_estimators': 100, 'max_depth': 3, 'learning_rate': 0.1, 'loss': 'lad'}
clf = GradientBoostingRegressor(**params).fit(x_train, y_train)
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
feature_importance=clf.feature_importances_
```

*other info* : I have 12 independent vars(x_train) and one label var(y_train)) with multiple values (say 4,5,7) and type(x_train) is  and type(feature_importance) is

*Acknowledgments* : Some elements are borrowed from this post  http://www.tonicebrian.com/2012/11/05/training-gradient-boosting-trees-with-python/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When initializing an [ExtraTreeClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.ExtraTreeClassifier.html), there is an option `compute_importances` which defaults to `None`. In other words, you need to initialize `ExtraTreeClassifier` as

```
clf = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=10,max_features='auto',random_state=0,compute_importances=True)
```

so that it will compute the feature importance.

Where as for [GradientBoostedRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html), there is no such option and feature importance will always be computed.

Comment: Works to get the compute_importances array - thank you and +1. Could you also mention HOW to select n_estimators ? On the scikit-learn documentation , there's little info on that- can I just randomize this and *see* which one is a good fit(by goodness of fit)?

Comment: When determining a "good fit", you probably want to monitor the prediction error on a validation set rather than the error on training set to avoid overfitting. E.g., you can try an increasing number of iterations, the training error should keep decreasing -- but you stop when the validation error starts growing.

Comment: compute_importances for ExtraTreeClassifier is in newer versions not needed any more